# Multiprocesssing manager shutdown gives error Access Denied

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, multiprocessing, ipc

I have a function that runs over a number of tables in a sqlite database. It reads the data, does some stuff and then saves the result in a csv-file.

```
from __future__ import division

import sqlalchemy as sql
import pandas as pd
import os
import multiprocessing as mp

dst = r'H:\Results'

eng = sql.create_engine('sqlite:///Y:/Database/some.db') # database on external drive
con = eng.connect() 

def get_res(tab_name,lock):
    query_tr = """SELECT t, p, size, event, direction \
    FROM {tb} WHERE event IN (4, 5)""".format(tb=tab_name)

    df_tr = pd.read_sql_query(query_tr,con)
    # do some stuff with df_tr ...

    with lock:
        df_tr.to_csv(os.path.join(dst,'my_res.csv'), mode='a')

    return 1
```

I do this in parallel like so

```
if __name__=='__main__':

    workers = mp.cpu_count()

    tables = sql.inspect(eng).get_table_names()

    man = mp.Manager()
    pool = mp.Pool(workers)
    lock = man.Lock()
    res = {tab_name: pool.apply_async(get_res,(tab_name,lock)) for tab_name in tables}
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    man.shutdown()
```

The strange thing is that the call `man.shutdown()` returns a `Windows Error 5: Access Denied` when the function reads the data from a database that is on an **external** hard disk drive, but works absolutely fine when the database is on the computer's hard drive. The function `get_res` goes through correctly without any error and does what it should do.

I know that this is not much to go on, but are there any suggestions why that could be the case?

Comment: why do you explicitly call `man.shutdown()`? The [docs say](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-managers): "Manager processes will be shutdown as soon as they are garbage collected or their parent process exits"

Comment: also the [docs say](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager.shutdown) you can only call `stop()` if you called `start()` before: "`stop()`: Stop the process used by the manager. This is only available if start() has been used to start the server process."